# developing timeseries for multiple centers using R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I need to develop a model to run time series for multiple centers at the same time. imagine I have 20 call centers,  dont want to run my code 20 time.

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/batch-forecasting/

I found this but cant change it to make auto arima

Comment: So what have you tried? and why it didn´t work? It could help if you could show your code and a data (sample) ..

Comment: I tried Rob Hyndman code, in the link. I need help to change that code to Arima. I just started and I am trying to learn as much as I can